# How to let the user attempt many times?

Tags: java, for-loop, random, char, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

/*
 *  1) the user can attempt many times and you need to display the number of successful attempt
 *  2) the range of random number 1..49
 *  3) output >> You successfully guess the number in 16 attempts
 *  4) output >> Do you want to play again?
 * */

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randNum = new Random();
        int guessNumber, number, count=0;
        String in;
        char again; 
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Guessing Game");
        do {
                number = randNum.nextInt(50); // random number in the range of 1..50
        
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter a number to guess: ");
                    guessNumber = uInput.nextInt(); // get guess number from user
                    
                    if(guessNumber > number)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Too big");
                    }else if(guessNumber < number)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Too small");
                    }else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        count+=1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("You successfully guess the number in "+count);
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? ");
                in = uInput.nextLine();
                
                again = in.charAt(0); //again will hold the first character from in var
                
        }while(again =='Y'|| again =='y');
        System.out.println("Guessing game terminate, thank you");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question by introducing your code with a couple of lines describing your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Guessing Game");
    guessNumber();
    System.out.println("Guessing game terminate, thank you");
}

private static void guessNumber() {
    Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randNum = new Random();
    int guessNumber, number, count = 0;
    String in;
    char again;
    boolean isCorrect = false;


    number = randNum.nextInt(50); // random number in the range of 1..50

    while (!isCorrect) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to guess: ");
        guessNumber = uInput.nextInt(); // get guess number from user

        count += 1;

        if (guessNumber > number) {
            System.out.println("Too big");
        } else if (guessNumber < number) {
            System.out.println("Too small");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Success");
            isCorrect = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You successfully guess the number in " + count + " attempts");
    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? yes/no");
    in = uInput.next();

    again = in.charAt(0); //again will hold the first character from in var
    if (again == 'Y' || again == 'y') {
        guessNumber();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to replace your do while loop with a while loop. But the point is that you must set an initial value 'Y' to your again char to start the while loop. the condition of the loop will be just the same. The code will be like : char again = 'Y';

```
    while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y') {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Guessing Game");
        number = randNum.nextInt(50);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number to guess: ");
            guessNumber = uInput.nextInt();

            if (guessNumber > number) {
                System.out.println("Too big");
            } else if (guessNumber < number) {
                System.out.println("Too small");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Success");
                count += 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("You have successfully guessed the number for " + count + " times");
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? ");
        in = uInput.next();

        again = in.charAt(0); //again will hold the first character from in var
    }

    System.out.println("Guessing game terminate, thank you");
```

I must note that your `count` variable, contains the number of games which user has guessed the number successfully, and not the number of attempts during a single game. If you want to handle this too, create `attempts` variable inside the while loop and increase it whenever the user attempts.
Also I changed the line `in = uInput.nextLine();` to `in = uInput.next();` because I believe your scanner input will be skipped.